# Detecting if a button has been pressed on the whole document

Tags: javascript, html, button, document, detect

I want to detect if a button has been pressed on a document. That means I don't want to put in `document.getElementById("ID").onclick` for each button. In other words, i want to detect if ANY button has been pressed on the document. If a button is pressed, get that button object, get it's textContent and that's all there is to it.

Comment: This is very simple using [jQuery](https://jquery.com) where you would do something like `$("input[type='button']").on("click", function() { console.log(this.value) });`

Comment: Hey, good news! It works like a charm. I don't personally use `<input type="button">` but I instead use '<button value="foo">foobar</button>' so I just went up replaced '$("input[type=button]")' to '$("button")' and now it works! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome - good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

buttons.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    btn.innerText = "CLICKED BUTTON"
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="button">1</button>
<button class="button">2</button>
<button class="button">3</button>
<button class="button">4</button>
```

Comment: Just be aware, arrow functions are [not supported in IE11 or earlier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#browser_compatibility) (fine on Edge) in case you need to support legacy browsers

Comment: @freefaller My bad, you are right. I updated the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick note, @freefaller. I literally used the arrow function everywhere on my projects without even thinking of compatibility. Replaced them all with function(), but sometimes I kinda need the arrow function though.